# Understanding static constexpr member variables

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

I have some confusions regarding `static constexpr` member variables in C++11.

### In first.hpp

```
template<typename T>
struct cond_I
{ static constexpr T value = 0; }; 


// specialization 
template<typename T>
struct cond_I< std::complex<T> >
{ static constexpr std::complex<T> value = {0,1}; };
```

### In main() function

```
cout << cond_I<double>::value << endl;            // this works fine
cout << cond_I< complex<double> >::value << endl; // linker error
```

However if I add the following line to `first.hpp` everything works fine.

```
template<typename T1> 
constexpr std::complex<T1> cond_I< std::complex<T1> >::value;
```

What I understand (I may be wrong) is, that `cond_I< std::complex<double> >::value` needs a definition, but in the previous case it only has the declaration. But then what about `cond_I<double>::value`? Why it does not require a definition?

Again, in another header file, `second.hpp`, I have:

### In second.hpp

```
// empty struct
template<typename T>
struct eps
{ };


// special cases
template<>
struct eps<double>
{
  static constexpr double value = 1.0e-12;
};

template<>
struct eps<float>
{
  static constexpr float value = 1.0e-6;
};
```

In this case, following codes works perfectly without any definition of `eps<>::value`.

### In main() function

```
cout << eps<double>::value << endl;    //  works fine
cout << eps<float>::value << endl;     //  works fine
```

Can someone please explain me the different behaviors of `static constexpr` member variables, in these scenarios?

These behaviors are also the same for `gcc-5.2` and `clang-3.6`.

Comment: I think the answer is that because `ostream::operator<<(ostream&, const complex<T> &)` passes by reference, this is considered *odr-use* of the argument, therefore you need a definition (for the reference to refer to).

Comment: Yes. Without taking any reference, first code works. `float` or `double` are passed by value, so the second code works. Thank you.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32812663/3093378

Comment: @vsoftco Thank you for the note. That thread contains some useful explanations. I didn't find it earlier.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to the standard *9.4.2/p3 Static data members [class.static.data]* (**Emphasis Mine**):

> If a non-volatile const static data member is of integral or enumeration type, its declaration in the class definition can specify a brace-or-equal-initializer in which every initializer-clause that is an assignment-expression is a constant expression (5.20). **A static data member of literal type can be declared in the class definition with the `constexpr` specifier; if so, its declaration shall specify a brace-or-equal-initializer in which every initializer-clause that is an assignment-expression is a constant expression. [ Note: In both
>   these cases, the member may appear in constant expressions. — end note ] The member shall still be defined in a namespace scope if it is odr-used (3.2) in the program and the namespace scope definition shall not
>   contain an initializer.**

As M.M earlier explained in the comments `ostream::operator<<(ostream&, const complex<T>&)` passes by reference so value is considered odr-used in the program. Thus, as the wording above dictates you have to provide a definition.

Now as you’ve already found out fundamental types are passed by value, that it is why no definition required.

Comment: for anyone else confused at this: from C++17, due to [changes that affect inline variables in general](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39653928/710951), the namespace definition becomes unnecessary (but still allowed / ignored for backwards compat)