# Why do I need to define a constexpr member already initialized in the declaration?

Tags: c++

Is there a reason why a fully initialized constexpr member have to be defined again outside the class declaration ?

Isn't it redundant since it's static, constant and already fully initialized inside the declaration ?

Here is an example. I am using C++17

```
#include <iostream>

struct Settings {
    static constexpr const char * str[2] = {"Hello 1", "Hello 2"};
};

void print(int i) {
    printf("%s\n", Settings::str[0]); // Does not need a definition
    printf("%s\n", Settings::str[i]); // Needs a definition
}

int main() {
    print(1);
    return 0;
}
```

The line :

```
printf("%s\n", Settings::str[i]);
```

generate this error :

```
undefined reference to `Settings::str'
```

But not the line :

```
printf("%s\n", Settings::str[0]);
```

Thanks

Comment: If you are *really* using C++17 it should not be needed, otherwise [Understanding static constexpr member variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34053606/understanding-static-constexpr-member-variables)

Comment: works fine with a c++17 compiler

Comment: I am using -std=c++17 with GCC 6.3.0. Maybe this feature is not already implemented in my version. Do you have the name the feature ?

Comment: I believe this was changed very late in the C++17 revision, long after gcc 6 was released. Formally everything is still "experimental" as the C++17 standard is still out on a formal vote by the ISO member countries.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help. I will try to find an updated version of gcc. It is a good thing they fixed this in the standard because it was a kind of code duplication for no reason