# Undefined refenence error when compiling with C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, linker, g++

The example program is here:

test.h

```
#pragma once
#include <bitset>

class Foo{
public:
    constexpr static std::bitset<9> hori1{0b111000000};
    bool Bar(const std::bitset<9> cells);
};
```

test.cpp

```
#include <bitset>
#include "test.h"

bool Foo::Bar(const std::bitset<9> cells){
    return hori1.any();
}

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

When compiling this program without the `--std=c++11` everything works fine.

```
$ g++ -c test.cpp
$ g++ test.o
```

But when the flag is included, I get this:

```
$ g++ -c --std=c++11 test.cpp
$ g++ test.o
/usr/bin/ld: test.o: warning: relocation against `_ZN3Foo5hori1E' in read-only section `.text'
/usr/bin/ld: test.o: in function `Foo::Bar(std::bitset<9ul>)':
test.cpp:(.text+0x17): undefined reference to `Foo::hori1'
/usr/bin/ld: warning: creating DT_TEXTREL in a PIE
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Why is this happening only in C++11? As far as I know, test.h is correctly included and therefore `hori1` should be visible from within `Foo`. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you get any issue if you do the compilation and linking in one call to g++? Wondering if there's some linking flag. Also, `0b` integer literal notation isn't legal until C++14. I guess gcc implemented it as an extension in 11?

Comment: @JohnFilleau It has the same behavior as when compiling and linking separately. Works without C++11 flag, doesn't work with it.

Comment: @Jan refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18749071/why-does-a-static-data-member-need-to-be-defined-outside-of-the-class

Comment: @long.kl This does not apply to constexpr static members. In fact, `constexpr static` members **must** be defined inside the class.

Answer (score 3):

`hori1` is `static`. You have to define `static` data members in the implementation of the class.

`test.cpp`:

```cpp
constexpr std::bitset<9> Foo::hori1;

bool Foo::Bar(const std::bitset<9> cells){
    return hori1.any();
}

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the header supposed to look like then? Static const data members require in-class initialization, so I can't leave only the declaration in the header file.

Comment: The declaration is correct in the header file, you can leave it as it was along with initialization.

Comment: It works, but it looks bizzare. The header file has the definition, but the declaration is in the cpp file. Is that really the correct way to do it?

Comment: @Jan you can keep the header as declaration and source file as definition of you prefer the way it looks.

Comment: @afekete I think that rule only applies to complex types. Basic types like `int` can be defined as static solely in the header.

Comment: @lurker That's the problem, I can't. `constexpr static` class members must have an in-class definition. You can't leave just the declaration in the header.

Comment: @Jan I'm not sure what you tried but I do this regularly. Let me be cleared though... Put the declaration in both places but the initializer in the source.

Comment: @lurker Yes, that works with `static` members, but NOT with `constexpr static`. If I put the line `constexpr static std::bitset<9> hori1;` *inside* my class, then I get the error: `error: ‘constexpr’ static data member ‘hori1’ must have an initializer`

Comment: @Jan ah I see. Yeah I had not tried it with constexpr. The constness requires the initializer in the header definition, but complex static variables must also be declared in the source.

Comment: According to the standard about `constexpr static` member variables: "A static data member of literal type can be declared in the class definition with the constexpr specifier; if so, its declaration shall specify a brace-or-equal-initializer in which every initializer-clause that is an assignment-expression is a constant expression."
This means you have to initialize complex types at declaration.
@lurker thank you for specifying the rule.
A similar post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34053606/understanding-static-constexpr-member-variables

Comment: @afekete I'm aware of that, and I implemented it correctly in the code in my question. Still, why doesn't the code link correctly then?

Comment: @Jan `std::bitset` isn't a "literal" type.

Answer (score 1):

The **problem** is that in C++11, we have to add a corresponding **definition** outside the class in exactly one translation unit for a **static constexpr declaration** of a class' data member(if odr-used). This is explained in more detail below:

#### C++11

```
class Foo
{
public:
    static constexpr int OUT_OF_BOUNDS_VALUE = -9999; //THIS IS A DECLARATION IN C++11 and C++14
    //other members here
};
```

In the above code snippet(which is for *C++11*,*C++14*), we have a **declaration** of the static data member `OUT_OF_BOUNDS_VALUE` inside the class. And so, in **exactly one translation unit** we have to provide a corresponding **definition**. Otherwise you'll get a **linker error** which can be seen [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vMt1YCUejxqBY12g).

That is, in **exactly one** translation unit we should write:

```
constexpr int Foo::OUT_OF_BOUNDS_VALUE;//note no initializer
```

After adding the above out of class definition with [**no initializer**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static#Constant_static_members) the program will work. [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/rj01yGYZe9yHLhqB)

#### C++17

```
class Foo
{
public:
    static constexpr int OUT_OF_BOUNDS_VALUE = -9999; //THIS IS A DEFINITION IN C++17
    //other members here
};
```

In the above code snippet(which is for *C++17*) we have a **definition** of the static data member `OUT_OF_BOUNDS_VALUE` inside the class. So since C++17, we don't have to provide the **definition** of `OUT_OF_BOUNDS_VALUE` anywhere else since we already have a definition for it inside the class and thus the same program [works](https://wandbox.org/permlink/n9lG0g1U3QowAZFo) without any linker error.

Comment: Could you explain why is the line in the cpp file called a "definition"? Also, why is it `constexpr const` and not `static constexpr`? Also what if it were just `constexpr` without the `const`? Thank you.

Comment: @Jan There is no `const` there. That was a typo that i forgot to remove. I have updated the examples in my answer. Check out my updated version.

Comment: @Jan Now coming to your other question about why the line in cpp file is a definition: From [Constant static members](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static#Constant_static_members): *"If a `const` non-inline (since C++17) static data member or a `constexpr` static data member (since C++11)(until C++17) is odr-used, a **definition** at namespace scope is still required, but it **cannot have an initializer**. A definition may be provided even though **redundant (since C++17)**. "*

Comment: @Jan Did you take a look at my edited answer? There is no `const` there.