# Constexpr variable captured inside lambda loses its constexpr-ness

Tags: c++, lambda, language-lawyer, c++17, if-constexpr

This code compiles fine in g++ ([coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cd6aa66a1615faa3)), but not MSVC ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/e1r5Rk) and my VS2017).

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
template<class T> void f(){
    constexpr bool b=std::is_same_v<T,int>; //#1
    auto func_x=[&](){
        if constexpr(b){ //#error
        }else{
        }
    };
    func_x();
}
int main(){
    f<int>();
}
```

> (6): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
>   (6): note: failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime
>    (6): note: see usage of 'this'

Which one (g++ or MSVC) is wrong?
What is `this` in  "*see usage of 'this'*"??

How to work around it while keep the compile-time guarantee?

In my real case, `b (#1)` is a complex statement depends on a few other constexpr variables.

Comment: Coliru uses GCC 8.2; GCC 8.3 from https://gcc.godbolt.org/ also rejects the code. Clang 7.0.0 compiles it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Gcc is right. `b` (as `constexpr` variable) doesn't need to be [captured](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) in fact.

> A lambda expression can read the value of a variable without capturing
>   it if the variable
>
> - is constexpr and has no mutable members.

[GCC LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/44QsiWEk6hBTAu50)

It seems if making `b` `static` then MSVC could access `b` without capturing.

```
template<class T> void f(){
    constexpr static bool b=std::is_same_v<T,int>;
    auto func_x=[](){
        if constexpr(b){
        }else{
        }
    };
    func_x();
}
```

[MSVC LIVE](https://godbolt.org/z/oR-liR)

And

> How to work around it while keep the compile-time guarantee?

We can't keep the constexpr-ness for the captured variables. They become non-static data members of the lambda closure type and [non-static data members can't be `constexpr`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27408819/3309790).

Comment: Is there a location in the C++ standard where this is stated?

Comment: Indeed, C++17 seems to [directly contradict this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.prim.lambda.capture#7). `b` is implicitly captured by the lambda; there is no caveat about being a constant expression.

Comment: @NicolBolas since `b` is `constexpr`, performing an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on it directly does not constitute an odr-use. See [basic.def.odr]/3 for the standard reference.

Answer (score 11):

> How to work around it while keep the compile-time guarantee?

Marking the `constexpr bool` as `static` serves as a work around.

See [**Demo**](https://godbolt.org/z/WzyaPm)

Alternately, you can use the condition in the `if constexpr` instead of assigning it to a `bool`. Like below:

```
if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T,int>)
```

See [**Demo**](https://godbolt.org/z/GpINY5)

Note that there have been bugs raised for MSVC regarding `constexpr` with respect to lambda expressions.
One such is: [**problems with capturing constexpr in lambda**](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/367326/problems-with-capturing-constexpr-in-lambda.html)
and another is: [**if constexpr in lambda**](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/200017/if-constexpr-in-lambda.html)

Comment: The bugs are closed as "fixed", but the fact is that the bugs are still there as of version 17.3.5 (Visual Studio Professional 2022)...